# Split string into array of words

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I want to split a `string` into an array of words without using `string.Split`. I tried already this code and it is working but cant assign the result into the array

```
string str = "Hello, how are you?";
string tmp = "";
int word_counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
     if (str[i] == ' ')
     {
         word_counter++;
     }
}
string[] words = new string[word_counter+1];

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if (str[i] != ' ')
    {
        tmp = tmp + str[i];
        continue;
    }
    // here is the problem, i cant assign every tmp in the array
    for (int j = 0; j < words.Length; j++)
    {
        words[j] = tmp;
    }
    tmp = "";
}
```

Comment: How is it working, but can't let you assign to the array? That means that something is not working. What does it do?

Comment: You should consider using `string.Substring` as you loop through the string keep track of the index of the last index for a space and then when you see a new one just substring from that index to the current.  Also make sure to do a final substring after the loop.  You can also keep track of the current word index to know where to put it in your `words` array.

Comment: based on your current code, you only need to keep track the current index of your word. See my answer as example. Don't forget the last assignment as it can be tricky.

Comment: But why can't you use `string.Split`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need a kind of `index pointer` to put up your item one by one to the array:

```
string str = "Hello, how are you?";
string tmp = "";
int word_counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == ' ') {
        word_counter++;
    }
}
string[] words = new string[word_counter + 1];
int currentWordNo = 0; //at this index pointer
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) {
    if (str[i] != ' ') {
        tmp = tmp + str[i];
        continue;
    }
    words[currentWordNo++] = tmp; //change your loop to this
    tmp = "";
}
words[currentWordNo++] = tmp; //do this for the last assignment
```

In my example the index pointer is named `currentWordNo`

Comment: @Omar Great, but I still wonder why can't you use `string.Split` which possibly the best available option? ;)

Comment: it is a homework :) and it is not allowed to use any inbuilt function

Answer (score 4):

Try using *regular expressions*, like this:

```
  string str = "Hello, how are you?";

  // words == ["Hello", "how", "are", "you"] 
  string[] words = Regex.Matches(str, "\\w+")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

`String.Split` is not a good option since there are *too many* characters to split on: `' '` (space), `'.'`, `','`, `';'`, `'!'` etc.

Word *is not* just a stuff between spaces, there are *punctuations* to consider, *non-breaking* spaces etc. Have a look at the input like this:

```
  string str = "Bad(very bad) input to test. . ."
```

Note

1. Absence of space after "Bad"
2. Non-breaking space
3. Addition spaces after full stops

And the right output should be

```
  ["Bad", "very", "bad", "input", "to", "test"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a List to create your words list:

```
    string str = "Hello, how are you?";
    string tmp = "";
    List<string> ListOfWords = new List<string>();

    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != ' ')
        {
            tmp = tmp + str[i];
            continue;
        }
        // here is the problem, i cant assign every tmp in the array

        ListOfWords.Add(tmp);
        tmp = "";
    }
    ListOfWords.Add(tmp);
```

In this way you can avoid to count the number of word and the code is more simple. Use ListOfWord[x] to read any word